# What do you call the problem of predicting a non-binary value for many parameters?

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, classification

I have some discrete decision variables -namely colour, texture, size and temperature- which clearly have many possible values and the object I observe will obviously have some value for all of these variables.

I would like to predict the values of all four variables while using the previous variable prediction as a feature; i.e.: first I predict the value for the colour using some features, then I add this prediction to my features and predict the value for texture, then the same for size and temperature.

What do you call this kind of problem?
What tools does sklearn offer to solve it?

Comment: I'm not sure that's really a good idea - your predicted features will necessarily be highly correlated with existing features - you're not adding new information. Still, for multi-output problems with sklearn, look at https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/multiclass.html#multioutput-classification

Comment: If you are predicting the two features f1={green|blue} and f2={grass|sky}, then it helps to know what the decision was for f1 when predicting f2. But yes, the classifier for f2 could just reconstruct that decision again.

Comment: Thats a classifier chain. Look at https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/multiclass.html#classifierchain

Answer (score 0):

The model that you describe is a generic factorization of a joint probability model. (A generative model, because it can be used to generate random plausible data points, not only predict a target label.)

If you have only discrete features, e.g. f1, f2, f3, the most you can learn about them is their joint probability P(f1, f2, f3). This is a table with a probability value for all possible combinations of features. From this you can make any prediction you want. That table is usually too large, you don't have enough data to estimate all the cells with certainty.

You can of course start by learning P(f1) only. You fill up a very small table. But once you have that, you can learn f2 for every given value f1: P(f2|f1). This is a larger table. And then you need P(f3|f1,f2) which is much larger yet again. This is always possible, and equivalent to learning the full table. So you haven't gained anything.

What you are proposing is to replace those "tables" with a predictor that has (hopefully) less parameters to be learned than the full table has entries. But with this you bias your model, so now it matters a lot which feature you pick first and how your learning method deals with dependencies. If f3 is actually independent of all the other features, then this can work very well, but if you already know this you can simply replace P(f3|f1,f2) with P(f3) and get back to learning this as an independent factor (aka very small table). If you follow that route, you end up modelling a [Bayesian network](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bayesian_network).